# Searching for one even and one odd number in string

Tags: python

So I'm going through old advent of codes and came across this one and it asks me to search each string to make sure it has at least one even and one odd number in it. However, my function doesn't correctly sort the list. It runs without errors, but it never filters anything and just prints out everything. I don't really know where I'm going wrong so if there are any pointers to fix it, I would gladly appreciate it.

```
def one_even_one_odd(pass_str: str) -> bool:
    for i in range(5):
        if pass_str[i] == pass_str % 2 == 0 and pass_str[i] == pass_str % 2 == 1:
            return True
    return False


def result(range_from: int, range_to: int) -> int:
    amount_passwords = 0
    each_password = []

    for password in range(range_from, range_to + 1):
        pass_str = str(password)
        if not pass_str == ''.join(sorted(pass_str)):
            continue
        if not one_even_one_odd(pass_str):
            continue
        each_password.append(pass_str)
        amount_passwords += 1

    return amount_passwords, each_password


def main():
    range_from = 138345
    range_to = 836215
    print(f'Amount of passwords followed by list of passwords: {result(range_from, range_to)}')
```

In this case, the list would print every number in the range for example "111, 112, 222" but I want it to only print 112 as that is the only number that contains at least one even and one odd number in it.

Comment: So, what is the expected and actual output? Please provide a [mcve], including that info! Also, try to find a tutorial how to use a debugger. Use that to step through the code and find out where it went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would use set operations:

```
odds = set('13579')
evens = set('02468')

def one_even_one_odd(string):
    S = set(string)
    return bool(odds & S) and bool(evens & S)
    
    
one_even_one_odd('ABCD125')
# True

one_even_one_odd('ABCD135')
# False
```